How to configure Microsoft 365 for unusual email routing requirements?
We have a Microsoft 365 tenant and have run into a problem with the routing of emails that is due to a unusual requirement.
We have connected the domain example.com to the tenant, and email that is sent to user@example.com is put into the Exchange mailbox for the respective user (Exchange Online). In most cases, this is the desired behavior.
However, for certain users, emails should not hit these users' Exchange Online mailboxes, but instead should be forwarded to another MX that handles these users' incoming messages. This seems impossible to achieve if there is the additional requirement that these users' Exchange Online mailboxes remain enabled.
To explain by example:
The users a@example.com and b@example.com both have have their Exchange Online mailbox enabled. Email messages to a@example.com should be put into the respective Exchange Online mailbox, but messages to b@example.com should be forwarded to another, external MX that handles inbound email for b@example.com, but not for a@example.com.
To make this happen, we have done the following:

Create a connector with the following properties:

Mail flow scenario: From Office 365 to Your organization's email server
Name: Bypass_Exchange
Status: On
Use of connector: Use only when I have a transport rule set up that redirects messages to this connector
Routing: Route email messages through these smart hosts: ‎mx.otherdomain.com
Security restrictions: (not relevant here)
Validation: Last validation result: ‎Validation successful‎ (rest of validation property not relevant here)


Create a rule with the following properties:

Status: Enabled
Rule name: Bypass_b
Mode: Enforce
Severity: Not specified
Set date range: Specific date range is not set
Senders address: Matching header
Priority: 0
For rule processing errors: Ignore
Apply this rule if: any of recipients' addresses matches these patterns: b@example.com
Do the following: Route the message using the connector named Bypass_Exchange
Rule comments: (none)



This works halfway:
If somebody sends email to a@example.com, the message arrives in the respective Exchange Online mailbox. If somebody sends email to b@example.com, the message is forwarded to mx.otherdomain.com, which handles it appropriately because it is configured to take care messages to b@example.com.
But if somebody sends email to both recipients (e.g., a@example.com and b@example.com are both in the To: header), things go wrong, and the sender gets a non-delivery notification.
I understand why this is the case: Microsoft 365 triggers the rule because a recipient address matches b@example.com, and forwards the message to mx.otherdomain.com, which in turn freaks out because it is not configured to handle email for a@example.com.
While having understood the problem, I couldn't find a solution to it, even after having closely looked into all possible conditions in the rule editor and their possible usage. In the mail flow settings in Microsoft 365, is it possible somehow to "split" incoming messages into two copies, where one copy goes only to the recipients that are handled by the Exchange Online mailboxes and the other copy goes only to the recipients that are handled by mx.otherdomain.com?

More useful information, you can refer to 1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/mail-flow-best-practices  2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow/set-up-connectors-to-route-mail

There are several options here.
The best solution would be to use a different SMTP domain on the external mail server; this way, you could either:

Configure a forwarder on the b@example.com mailbox to forward messages to b@example2.com
Remove the mailbox altogether and replace it with a contact, which does pretty much the same but without an actual Exchange Online mailbox existing.

If you instead actually need to share the same SMTP domain between Exchange Online and an external mail server, things become a lot more complex.

Thanks for the fast reply, accepted and +1. Option 1 is what we have worked out, too. Option 2 is not for us, because the Exchange Online Mailbox needs to be active for those special users, too. Another idea would be to reverse option 1: Let the external MX handle mail for all users, keeping messages for the special users on the external MX, but forwarding messages for normal users to example.onmicrosoft.com and letting them go to the Exchange Online mailboxes (example.onmicrosoft.com is an additional domain that was automatically created when creating the tenant).
